# Do we need mutex for accessing the data field in singleton object in C++11 - Multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

As per my understanding, the C++ 11 has static - thread safe. This means that there is no problem in getting/creating the instance of a singleton. This is because the static is thread safe now, and it will not cause any issue in the multi threaded environment. However, the question is do I need a mutex for accessing the data field in a singleton. Is it really related to singleton? Is mutex required even when the pattern is not singleton while accessing the data field in the multi-threaded environment. Here is the entire code.

```
class Singleton
{
private:

Singleton()
{
   std::cout<<"Singleton Initialized"<<std::endl;
}

Singleton(Singleton const&)
{
   std::cout<<"Singleton copy constructor not allowed"<<std::endl;
}

Singleton& operator=(Singleton const&)
{
   std::cout<<"Singleton Assignment Operator not allowed"<<std::endl;
}

~Singleton()
{
   std::cout<<"Singleton Destructor not allowed"<<std::endl;
}

int m_data;

public:

int getData()
{
   return m_data;
}

void setData(int data)
{
   m_data = data;

}

static Singleton * instance( )
{
   static Singleton *single_manager = new Singleton();
   return single_manager;

}

};
```

Comment: depends on what your tradeoffs are. Generally speaking, it will depend on your use case.

Comment: setter method I mean.

Comment: So you have choices in types of locks you can use to wrap setters, including nothing of course.

Comment: [OT]: You may use `=delete` to forbid copy constructor/assignment.

Comment: Thread safety of instantiating a singleton is 100% orthogonal to the thread safety of that singleton maintaining its invariants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: Yes.

C++ 11 "static threadsafe" prevents a race condition in:

```
static Singleton *single_manager = new Singleton();
```

Without that, possible issues are:

- Singleton() instantiated twice
- different threads seeing different instances of Singleton
- Singleton initialization not visible to other threads

However, any access to `m_data` (i.e. both `GetData` and `SetData`) need a mutex when they are called from different threads.

---

**Where to lock** - should the singleton have a lock inside, or should the caller lock?
(as per comment)

This question has no simple answer.

**I** would add a lock to the singleton class and lock in GetData / SetData. Rationale: almost always this is the default use case and removes burden from the caller.

**But:**
The inner lock is not always sufficient, e.g. if you have:

```
Singleton * s = Singleton::instance();
int x = s->GetData();
x = x + 1;
s->SetData(x);
```

the caller needs to use an outer lock around the Get/Modify/Set.

The argument *against* an inner lock is as follows:

- the inner lock is not sufficient in the general case, i.e. 
  there are cases where callers need their own lock
- when the caller has to lock anyway, the inner lock becomes a performance issue that can be significant.

**Conclusion:**  If you can avoid the get-modify-set scenario for the data at hand, it seems prudent to add an inner lock (e.g. the API could include an `IncrementData`) method. Clearly document the thread safety of the interface (e.g. *"this class is not thread safe and requires external locking"* or *"individual function calls are threadsafe"*)

---

Notes:

And yes: as you already thought: nothing of this is related to the class being a singleton.
If the data is really just an int, an "atomic integer" (e.g. from boost:.atomic) can be used instead. the get/set/modify problem remains, though.

Comment: So, the best way would be to have mutex outside the method or inside the method? Before accessing the method, the user will lock the mutex. Or do you suggest to put the mutex inside the method only.

Comment: Gcc,Clang are ok with thread safe static init. In Microsoft compiler it is availaible starting with vs 2015. Visual 2013 and before miss it and need mutex for this initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

> C++ 11 has static - thread safe

Only *function scope static* object initialization is thread safe.

> do I need a mutex for accessing the data field in a singleton.

If an object is accessed by more than one thread and at least one of the threads is a writer, then this is a data race and you need a mutex.

In some cases when you shared data is of integral types you can get away with using atomics from C++11 or their pre-standard equivalents. Like in your case:

```
std::atomic<int> m_data;
```